# getdata from another collection MongoDB aggregate $lookup

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I have the following two collections: `warehouses` and `products`

The Warehouse document structure looks like this:

```
{
  _id: ObjectId("5f17dc2309ce612aa858b625")
  products:[ // product is string
    {product: "5f17dc3a09ce612aa858b627", count: 20}, 
    {product: "5f17dc3a09ce612aa858b628", count: 10}
  ] 
}
```

And the Product document structure looks like this:

```
{
  _id: ObjectId("5f17dc3a09ce612aa858b627")
  name: "Tomatos",
  price: 5
}
```

I need to replace the `warehouse.products.product` value with the product with the same id from the `products` collection using an `aggregate`.

I think `.populate('products.product')` works fine //not sure// when use find, but now need with aggregate

I'm looking for this as a final result in the warehouse collection:

```
{
_id: ObjectId("5f17dc2309ce612aa858b625")
    products:[
        {
           
           count:20,
              product: {
                  name: "Tomatos",
                  price: 5
    }
        },
        {
           count:10,
           product: {
                name: "Oranges",
                price: 8
    }
        }
    ] 
}
```

I tried this, but it's not working:

```
{
   $lookup:
     {
       from: "products",
       let: { "pr": "products.product"},
        pipeline: [
      { $addFields: { "id": { "$toString": "$_id" }}},
                  { $match: { $expr: { $eq: [ "$id", "$$pr" ] } } }

    ],
       as: "products.product"
     }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
[{
    $unwind: {
        path: '$products'
    }
}, {
    $lookup: {
        from: 'item',
        'let': {
            pr: '$products.product'
        },
        pipeline: [{
            $match: {
                $expr: {
                    $eq: [{
                            $toString: '$_id'
                        },
                        '$$pr'
                    ]
                }
            }
        }],
        as: 'products.product'
    }
}, {
    $project: {
        "products.count": 1,
        "products.product": {
            $ifNull: [{
                    $arrayElemAt: ["$products.product", 0]
                },
                {

                }
            ]

        }
    }
}, {
    $group: {
        _id: '$_id',
        products: {
            $addToSet: '$products'
        }
    }
}]
```

Working [Mongo playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/izkTA3B8cfJ)

`lookup` provides an array. In your case you need the product object. So I hope the product always has one object. That's why I get first object from the array by using `arrayElemAt`, wrapped with `ifNull` because, sometimes the product array can have no elements.

Comment: Its working but this way I am losing all the other data that i have in warehouse I mean if its not just "_id" and "products".. also the same inside the "products" fields .. if there is no just the id and count

Comment: Replace the `unwind` by `{ $unwind: { path: '$products', preserveNullAndEmptyArrays: true } }`

Comment: its not helping :(
https://mongoplayground.net/p/vh9K_zsO2mF
you can check here i added to the warehouse "name" and "opened" props that are not appearing in the result also qty in the products collection
EDITED: Also i dont want to write all the fileds that i want to see inside the aggreagate
EDIT2: If its possible just to copy everythink and replace warehouse.products.*every procuts*.product with the respectivе product from products collection

Comment: This is what you looking for. https://mongoplayground.net/p/zIJmOOp8vVA . You need to look https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/project/ and https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/group/

Comment: And when you ask anything in stackoverflow, please check everything you included. You are responded what you ask in the main question,